# AUEffectBase.h onIOS in xcode?

Tags: ios

Is it possible to use AUEffectbase.h on IOS xcode 4.2? I'm trying to use it in a cpp file and it's telling me it does not exist. DO I need to get another framework or can I not use this? I am new to xcode.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AUEffectBase only exists in the CoreAudio SDK on MacOS only at this point.

[Here is documentation developer.apple.com](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/MusicAudio/Conceptual/AudioUnitProgrammingGuide/AudioUnitClassHierarchy/AudioUnitClassHierarchy.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40003278-CH9-SW2) describing where/how it is invoked.

Comment: Is there an equivalent in IOS?

Comment: Not yet, but keep wishing, it might appear in a subsequent iOS version down the road.  If you are a registered developer, file a bug and ask for it via http://bugreporter.apple.com

Comment: Thanks, I am a registered user. I'm trying to synth some output buffer and that would have helped me. Since I just realized IOS 5 now has built in effects, which I don't know how to use.